# Is it possible to use pointers to write directly (low level) onto a window without using Bitblt?

Tags: windows, gdi

I have written an anaglyph filter that mixes two images into one stereographic image.  It is a fast routine that works with one pixel at a time.
Right now I'm using pointers to output each calculated pixel to a memory bitmap, then Bitblt that whole image onto the window.

This seems redundant to me.  I'd rather copy each pixel directly to the screen, since my anaglyph routine is quite fast.  Is it possible to bypass Bitblt and simply have the pointer point directly to wherever Bitblt would copy it to?

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow.  I'm not sure which to mark as the answer since I don't really know it for sure myself!  Can you help me out?

Comment: You should mark as answer one that did answer your question. If none does, it's OK to leave it for a while in the wait for possible better answers, but it's generally frowned upon not to accept answers to many questions (the percentage of accepted answers will be shown next to your username if it's too low or too high and some people may not answer your questions based on that).

Comment: How do I choose between ones that do answer?  It looks like I've got three fairly good answers here.

Comment: I'll just mark the first.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it's possible, but you really really really don't want to do this. It's much more efficient to draw the entire pattern at once.

Comment: Why would it be more efficient to copy to a buffer and copy that to the screen than copying straight to the screen?  Is there something I don't know about low level graphics?

Comment: Because there is no copy direct to screen. that's what a blit does. Drawing directly on the screen you're drawing one pixel at a time.

Comment: Actually, my routine is already working on each pixel one at a time to mix the two images and storing it in a bitmap, then copying to the screen.  I'm wondering if I can put each pixel directly on screen instead of putting each pixel in a buffer and copying that over.

Comment: Because the user could see it mid-draw.

Comment: I'd still like to try it.  My routine is fast (2.7x faster than GDI+'s DrawImage itself), and in any case I'd like to know how to do this.  Thanks for your input though!

Comment: @jnm2 GDI+ DrawImage is *SLOW* IMO.

Comment: You're right.  I just realized that the reason DrawImage wasn't flickering was that I have the DWM enabled and everything is double buffered anyway.  It is slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't draw directly to the screen from windows because the graphics card memory isn't necessarily mapped in any sane order.

Bltting to the screen is amazingly fast.

Remember you don't blt after each pixel - only when you want a new result to be shown, even then there's no point doing this faster than the refresh on your screen - probably 60hz

Comment: Windows itself has it mapped, of course.  I was hoping there was some way to get Windows to tell me where it would draw to, but you're right: Bitblt is fast.  I still wish I could do a speed comparison, but I guess I'll be content.

Comment: Windows has the graphics card memory mapped onto the PCI address space. But the graphics driver and card's onboard engine could arrange that however it wants - it could store red/green/blue in diferent planes, it could store double buffers in different formats it could store rows in any order. It doesn't have to have 1920x1080x24bits contiguously

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like glMapBuffer in OpenGL, but acessing directly to the screen.

But writing to the GPU memory pixel per pixel is the slower operation you can do. PCI works faster if you send big streams of data. Also, there are many issues if you write and read data. And the pixel layout is also important (see nvidia docs about fast texture transfers). Bitblt will do it for you in a driver optimised way.